# Extra files in bin folder on publish

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Using VS 2019. I noticed that when I publish my .net project, some additional folders (such as folders with images) are being put in the bin folder. Where is this issue stemming from? All I want are the standard dll files, etc.

Comment: Post your .csproj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the File Properties window (bottom right with the default workspace layout), you'll see "Copy to Output Directory". If you have "Copy always" or "Copy if newer" then this file will be copied to the output bin folder. Change this to "Do no copy" and it will not appear. Note that you will need to select "Build" -> "Clean Solution" first as just doing a Build doesn't clear out existing files in the bin folder.